# Analogs for FindWindow, SetParent and MoveWindow WinAPI functions in iPadOS and macOS

Tags: windows, macos, winapi, posix, ipados

I have a Windows OS application that runs as 2 separate processes.
processA has its own window, and processB also has its own window which is binded inside window of processA with usage of WinAPI calls.

I am going to rewrite this application for iOS, and to do so, I should replace 3 main steps which use WinAPI calls:

1. When processA started, it searches for the processB window via call to FindWindow:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa
2. When window of process is successfully found, it is binded inside processA window via call to SetParent:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent
3. When parent changed, position/size of processB window can be changed by calls to MoveWindow:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow

The main question is - does iPadOS or macOS provide some similar API to manipulate windows of different processes?

For now I did not find API that I can use for such purposes with C/C++

Comment: Mobile platforms are fundamentally different than desktop platforms. I seriously doubt you will be able to achieve what you are asking for. You should rethink your core design for mobile.

Comment: I was wrong in the details. I changed iOS to IPadOS and macOS in the description. So probably somethink like this available at least with macOS

Comment: Probably not. You should think about solving your problem the right way on the target platform and not a literal mapping between them.